IP Class subnetting
Test question:

Which class of IP provides 15 bits for subnetting?
a) A
b) B
c) C
d) D

Answer:

A. Class A addressing provides 22 bits for host subnetting, class B provides 16 bits but only 14 are available for subnetting. Class C provides only 6 bits for subnetting.

Class A has 24 bits for host subnetting, class B has 16 bits and class C has 8 bits. Why are only 22, 14 and 6 bits available, respectively?

Please dont use images for text information.  Type it in!!!

because at least two bits are necessary for the host range. the smallest IP subnetwork you can have requires 4 IP addresses, so 2 bits. 22 subnet bits (30 network+subnetwork bits) will give you about 4 million subnets of 4 IPs each (2 of which are usable for end systems).

Classes were abolished in 1993, even before the rise of the commercial Internet and affordable networking. Please, simply forget about them. Classes haven't existed for longer than many current network administrators haven been alive!

@FrankThomas: That is not correct. RFC 3021 specifies /31 prefixes. (Although, to be fair, this question seems to have time-travelled from the 1980s, which is before RFC 3021 existed.)

@RohitGupta Understood, I'm sorry for that. For the answer part was trying to show that I wasn't making that up.

@FrankThomas Actually, /31 Networks were introduced by RFC 3021 in 2000.

@Zac67, and yet ironically, I would have gotten the answer right ;-)
